# Can I upgrade release without installing all package updates?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, 20.10, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade Ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04. When I type `do-release-upgrade -d`, I get a message "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading." I have one package held back, specifically xserver-xorg-core. I **do not** want to upgrade this package because of a bug it has, I need to continue using an older version. How can I still upgrade Ubuntu?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. The script is designed that way.

Comment: If that version of the package is compatible with 21.04, you could downgrade that package after you upgraded the system to 21.04. That doesn't sound like a good idea though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't *safely* upgrade if you're holding back packages for any reason.

You will need to install the updated `xserver-xorg-core` in order to upgrade to a newer version of the package.  You may be able to 'downgrade' that package later, but it is unlikely.  Unfortunately, there's no way around this - the upgrade script assumes that you're on the latest version, and needs that 'latest version for your release' in order to reliably upgrade you to the next release.